# Create Spatial Data in R

Tags: r, spatial

I have a dataset of species and their rough locations in a 100 x 200 meter area.  The location part of the data frame is not in a format that I find to be usable.  In this 100 x 200 meter rectangle, there are two hundred 10 x 10 meter squares named A through CV.  Within each 10 x 10 square there are four 5 x 5 meter squares named 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively (1 is south of 2 and west of 3.  4 is east of 2 and north of 3).  I want to let R know that A is the square with corners at (0 ,0), (10,0), (0,0), and (0,10), that B is just north of A and has corners (0,10), (0,20), (10,10), and (10,20), and K is just east of A and has corners at (10,0), (10,10), (20,0), and (20,10), and so on for all the 10 x 10 meter squares.  Additionally, I want to let R know where each 5 x 5 meter square is in the 100 x 200 meter plot.

So, my data frame looks something like this

```
10x10    5x5     Tree    Diameter
A    1     tree1    4
B    1     tree2    4
C    4     tree3    6
D    3     tree4    2
E    3     tree5    3
F    2     tree6    7
G    1     tree7    12
H    2     tree8    1
I    2     tree9    2
J    3     tree10   8
K    4     tree11   3
L    1     tree12   7
M    2     tree13   5
```

Eventually, I want to be able to plot the 100 x 200 meter area and have each 10 x 10 meter square show up with the number of trees, or number of species, or total biomass 
What is the best way to turn the data I have into spatial data that R can use for graphing and perhaps analysis?

Comment: by the way, I'm a little confused about the geometry of your area.  You have 100 10x10 plots (A to CV), apparently arranged in rows of 10 -- doesn't that make a 100x100 rather than a 100x200 area? (You also refer to it as a "square" at one point above ...)

Comment: I am typing on a phone, sorry about that. It's fixed now.  I'm working now to adapt the code to my actual data, since this was a bit if an abstraction. Thanks so much for the help. This is a clever way to get at the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a start.

```
## set up a vector of all 10x10 position tags
tags10 <- c(LETTERS,
            paste0("A",LETTERS),
            paste0("B",LETTERS),
            paste0("C",LETTERS[1:22]))
```

A function to convert (e.g.) `{"J",3}` to the center of the corresponding sub-square.

```
convpos <- function(pos10,pos5) {
    ## convert letters to major (x,y) positions
    p1 <- as.numeric(factor(pos10,levels=tags10))  ## or use match()
    p1.x <- ((p1-1) %% 10) *10+5    ## %% is modulo operator
    p1.y <- ((p1-1) %/% 10)*10+5    ## %/% is integer division
    ## sort out sub-positions
    p2.x <- ifelse(pos5 <=2,2.5,7.5)   ## {1,2} vs {3,4} values
    p2.y <- ifelse(pos5 %%2 ==1 ,2.5,7.5)  ## odd {1,3} vs even {2,4} values
    c(p1.x+p2.x,p1.y+p2.y)
}
```

usage:

```
convpos("J",2)
convpos(mydata$tenbytenpos,mydata$fivebyfivepos)
```

Important notes:

- this is a proof of concept, I can pretty much guarantee I haven't got the correspondence of x and y coordinates quite right.  But you should be able to trace through this line-by-line and see what it's doing ...
- it should work correctly on vectors (see second usage example above): I switched from `switch` to `ifelse` for that reason
- your column names (`10x10`) are likely to get mangled into something like `X10.10` when reading data into R: see `?data.frame` and `?check.names`

Comment: Perfect. It handles vectors a inputs just fine.  To get 2 vectors, one of x coordinates and one of y coordinates you can write `x.coords <- convpos(pos10, pos5)[1:(length(pos10)/2)]` and `y.coords <- convpos(pos10, pos5)[(1 + length (pos10)/2: length (pos10)]`.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what @Ben Bolker has done, here's a lookup function (though you may need to transpose something to make the labels match what you describe).

```
tenbyten <- c(LETTERS[1:26], 
  paste0("A",LETTERS[1:26]), 
  paste0("B",LETTERS[1:26]), 
  paste0("C",LETTERS[1:22]))

tenbyten <- matrix(rep(tenbyten, each = 2), ncol = 10)
tenbyten <- t(apply(tenbyten, 1, function(x){rep(x, each = 2)}))
# the 1234 squares
squares <- matrix(c(rep(c(1,2),10),rep(c(4,3),10)), nrow = 20, ncol = 20)
# stick together into a reference grid
my.grid <- matrix(paste(tenbyten, squares, sep = "-"), nrow = 20, ncol = 20)

# a lookup function for the site grid
coordLookup <- function(tbt, fbf, .my.grid = my.grid){
  x <- col(.my.grid) * 5 - 2.5
  y <- row(.my.grid) * 5 - 2.5
  marker <- .my.grid == paste(tbt, fbf, sep = "-")
  list(x = x[marker], y = y[marker])
}

coordLookup("BB",2)
$x
[1] 52.5

$y
[1] 37.5
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, then maybe you'd prefer a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`, which has proper polygon IDs, and you attach data to, etc. In that case just Google around for how to make one from scratch, and manipulate the `row()` and `col()` functions to get your polygon corners, similar to what's given in this lookup function, which only returns centroids.

Edit: getting SPDF started:

This is modified from the function example and can hopefully be a good start:

```
library(sp)
# really you have a 20x20 grid, counting the small ones.
# c(2.5,2.5) specifies the distance in any direction from the cell center
grd <- GridTopology(c(1,1), c(2.5,2.5), c(20,20)))
grd <- as.SpatialPolygons.GridTopology(grd)
# get centroids
coords <- coordinates(polys)
# make SPDF, with an extra column for your grid codes, taken from the above.
# you can add further columns to this data.frame(), using polys@data
polys <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(grd, 
  data=data.frame(x=coords[,1], y=coords[,2], my.ID = as.vector(my.grid), 
  row.names=getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(grd)))
```