# R - Plot Spatial Frequency Data as Matrix

Tags: r, plot, spatial, frequency

I want to do something really easy but cannot figure out how.

#### What I got:

A dataset of trees (35 species) found in various locations (30) which were in different elevations (--> 30 levels as well). My aim is now to visualize the information of the elevations the trees were found in. However, since most of them were quite scattered, I do have a lot of intraspecific variation.

#### What I want:

I just want a plot where y is the elevation and x the tree species. Each combination of elevation and species should be represented as a square color-coding the number of tree individuals. This should then result in a panel of squares similar to a discreet heatmap.

#### What I found:

Since I'm at loss, how you would call such a plot, I did not find anything useful. After searching for [spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117113/create-spatial-data-in-r) (or [here](http://www.leec.eco.br/pdfs/Support_Landscape_ecology_R_2016_06_15.pdf) and [here](http://ecology.msu.montana.edu/labdsv/R/labs/lab1/lab1.html)) and [frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626915/r-graph-frequency-of-observations-over-time-with-small-value-range) or even [presence/absence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358516/presence-and-absence-mapping-in-r) data, I ended up with a lot of overcomplicated stuff which still won't help me...

#### Example Data.Frame:

```
data.frame(elevation = c(103, 260, 307, 505),
 spec1 = c(0, 1, 4, 0),
 spec2 = c(11, 15, 4, 7),
 spec3 = c(3, 1, 5, 5),
 spec4 = c(5, 1, 1, 1))
```

*(I'm sorry the title is really crappy, I just couldn't think of any!)*

Comment: Actually, I discovered this is definitely a **duplicate** of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12998372/heatmap-like-plot-but-for-categorical-variables). I'm sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(elevation = c(103, 260, 307, 505),
 spec1 = c(0, 1, 4, 0),
 spec2 = c(11, 15, 4, 7),
 spec3 = c(3, 1, 5, 5),
 spec4 = c(5, 1, 1, 1))

library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    gather(species, value, 2:5) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = species, y = elevation, fill = value)) + geom_tile();
```

[image]

Comment: Even though the question is a duplicate, your answer solves it much more elegant, thanks!

Comment: No worries @bamphe, glad it helped.